# ServletRequest filter test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit, mockito

I have a filter that looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Get the servlet request
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    ... Some logic code here ...

    if (!accepted.contains(req.getRequestURI())) {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.sendError(404, "Some Error");
        return;
    }

    // Pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The problem is with my test case. Normally I would use mockito to mock the `HttpServletRequest`  something like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("the test URI");
```

However, the fact that the `HttpServletRequest` is obtained inside the method by casting I'm not sure the best way to test various URI requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be still be able to call your servlet with doFilter like:

```
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("the test URI");
HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
//mock method calls on response, replay
myServlet.filter(request, response);
```

It's fine even if it internally does type casting.

Comment: No worries mate.. it happens.. and SO is always there besides you to resolve issues.